# How do I Call Ajax for the first time after page loads?

Tags: ajax

here is my code:

```
  ...
    <script type="text/javascript">
function ajaxcall(div, page)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById(div).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET",page,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
 <tr>

  <td width="309" valign="top">

  <div width="309" height="270" id="menu"></div>
   <script type="text/javascript">ajaxcall('menu', 'map2.php')</script>
....
```

i want when the page loads it does the ajax and attach to the div "menu! the map2.php but it doesnt, what im doing wrong?

Comment: What does it do instead of what you're expecting?  Are there any JavaScript errors?

Comment: i really dont know if i should call  <script type="text/javascript">ajaxcall('menu', 'map2.php')</script> im just trying

Comment: well none are shown, it just doesnt load it to the div, it keeps  blank

Comment: A really good debugging tool is to install the Firebug extension for Firefox (or HTTP watch, Fiddler, etc. for IE) so you can monitor the requests made by your browser.  You should make sure that map2.php is even being requested.

Comment: ok ill install it and see what is wrong

Comment: Funny it works on firefox but not on chrome!

Comment: It seems to work for me, by the way.  Maybe your 'map2.php' cannot be found or is causing an error.  Firebug should show you a 404 or 500 respectively for those cases.

Comment: but it is working on firefox, but not on chrome, and thats weird

Comment: Are you testing this in a php file running on your web server or as a local HTML file on your computer?  If it's a local file, keep in mind that Chrome will get a "Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin" error, just as if you were loading content cross-domain.

Comment: Is the PHP you're loading on the same server as the host page?

Comment: yes the file is in the same server and folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things to check:

Its the DOM you are using available when the script is called?

The function has to be called in order to do the request. And more importantly the dom elements used in the function must exist. To make sure the node exists place the your function call after the div has closed in an inline script tag, or attach an event handler to window load event or use a js framework domready/domloaded/ready ( same thing different names ) event

Its the request being sent?
Use Firefox with Firebug extension to fugure it out

Are they any error/exceptions not allowing the js run?
Use firebug to check for errors

Hope this helps

PS: xhhtrequest.onerror should be called in the event of a bad request, if you cannot use firebug attach a function to alert for errors

Comment: thanks, ive done the firebug and in the console it DOES request and no errors are shown , and works fine but in chrome isnt, im still looking for the error

Comment: i checked the chrome web debugger and it calls the page but still dont show, keep on investigation

Comment: Do an alert to see if the onreadystate change is being called at all, also add an onerror function to check for weird errors that may not be related to the connection

Comment: interesting enough it was my chat script which uses ajax too but i havent wrote it, simply putting the script after the script it now works, thanks you and jacob

Comment: Glad to help,So both scripts were using the window.onload? And overwritting each other?

Comment: i dont know about the chat script, but it just is screwing up the whole thing... hahaha ill try to do myself.